# Ошибка, при работе с библиотекой pyown

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

При работе с pyown, выдается ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bqich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bqich\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\WeatherApp.py", line 8, in btn_click
    w = observation.get_weather()
AttributeError: 'Observation' object has no attribute 'get_weather'
```

Пытался найти ответ в google, но как заменить данный метод, так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

*Используйте документацию*

[Документация pyowm](https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3/code-recipes.html#get-current-weather-status-on-a-location)

*Обновите библиотеку pyowm*

**pip install -U pyowm**

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

configuration = get_default_config()
configuration['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('your-api-key', configuration)

def weather(city):
    weather_manager = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = weather_manager.weather_at_place(city)
    detailed_status = observation.weather.detailed_status

    temperature = observation.weather.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    print("{0}:\n    погода: {1}\n    температура {2}".format(city, detailed_status, temperature))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    weather("Москва")
```